# Selection bar implementation in xtype-selectfield same as datepickerfield

Tags: html, css, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In Sencha touch version 2.3.0 we have xtype:'datepickerfield' for which we have a default bar that indicates the selected date.

[image: Blue line indicates selected date]

This selection blue bar can be modified using following css property.

```
.x-picker-bar {
  background: rgba(247, 109, 48, 0.6);
}
```

[image: datepickerfield with changed CSS]

Now we have another component with xtype:'selectfield'. I want to implement this bar to this component as well. How can this be implemented? Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: You can just inspect the element to get its class then add a CSS rule for your desired effect

Comment: @Aziz already tried that sir. No success.

Comment: we would appreciate a demo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below `css` will serve your purpose Pushkar:

```
.x-picker-slot .x-dataview-item.x-item-selected {
    background: rgba(247, 109, 48, 0.6) !important;
}
```

Let me know it helps or not.